# With the exception of, or and, in if statement

Tags: objective-c, xcode, if-statement

I have an if statement:

```
if ([txt.text isEqualToString:@"8"]) {
    [self q7done];
} else {
    Fail *fail = [[Fail alloc]
                  initWithNibName:@"Fail" bundle:nil];
    fail.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:fail animated:YES];

}
```

How can I make it that if txt.text isEqualToString, 8 OR, Eight. I tried:

```
if ([txt.text isEqualToString:@"8", @"Eight"]) {
    [self q7done];
} else {
    Fail *fail = [[Fail alloc]
                  initWithNibName:@"Fail" bundle:nil];
    fail.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:fail animated:YES];

}
```

BUt I got an error saying too many arguments

Comment: in future, try not to include code irrelevent to your problem. That stuff about Fail, modalTransitionStyle, clearly has nothing to do with your problem, so don't include it.

Comment: +1 for trying something before asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ([txt.text isEqualToString:@"8"] || [txt.text isEqualToString:@"Eight"])
```

Please Google "C logical and or operator" to get numerous tutorials on it.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do something like:

```
if ([txt.text isEqualToString:@"8"] || [txt.text isEqualToString:@"Eight"]) {
```

The `||` here means "or", so either the left or the right clause (or both, but that wouldn't happen in this case) needs to be `true` for the result to be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([txt.text isEqualToString:@"8"] || [txt.text isEqualToString:@"Eight"]) {
    ....
```

or

```
NSArray *options = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"8", @"Eight", nil];
if ([options containsObject:txt.text]) {
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Use || operator like below ...

```
 if ([txt.text isEqualToString:@"8"] || [txt.text isEqualToString:@"Eight"]) {
   NSLog(@"Condition true");
 }
 else 
 {
   NSLog(@"Condition failed");
 }
```